# Десериализация XML c разным корневым элементом

Tags: c#, .net, xml, сериализация, десериализация

У меня есть два xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ClientCreditShortInfoListType>
  <Error>
    <ErrorCode>1</ErrorCode>
    <ErrorText>Общая ошибка</ErrorText>
  </Error>
</ClientCreditShortInfoListType>
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ClientCreditShortInfoList>
  <Error>
    <ErrorCode>1</ErrorCode>
    <ErrorText>Общая ошибка</ErrorText>
  </Error>
</ClientCreditShortInfoList>
```

Так же есть класс для сериализации:

```cs
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "ClientCreditShortInfoListType", Namespace = FindListCreditByClientIDConst.namespaceResponse)]
public class FindListCreditByClientIDResponse
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Error", Namespace = FindListCreditByClientIDConst.namespaceResponse)]
    public Error Error { get; set; }
}
```

Есть ли способ для сериализации(десериализации) использовать один класс, и обрабатывать xml одинаковые по сути, но разным Root. В одном случае это `ClientCreditShortInfoListType` в другом `ClientCreditShortInfoList` ?

Answer (score 1):

Сделайте общий класс

```
class CreditShortInfor {
 [XmlElement(ElementName="Error")]
 Error error;     
}

public static CreditShortInfor Deserialize(XmlReader reader)
 {
    reader.MoveToContent();
    string rootName = reader.Name;
    var serializer  = new XmlSerializer(typeof(CreditShortInfor), 
        new XmlRootAttribute(rootName)
        );
    var deserialized = serializer.Deserialize(reader) as CreditShortInfor;
    return deserialized;
 }
```

....

```
var creditShortInfor  = Deserialize(XmlReader.Create(
new StringReader("<ClientCreditShortInfoListType>
<Error>
    <ErrorCode>1</ErrorCode>
    <ErrorText>Общая ошибка</ErrorText>
  </Error>
</ClientCreditShortInfoListType>"))
);

creditShortInfor  = Deserialize(XmlReader.Create(
new StringReader("<ClientCreditShortInfoList>
<Error>
    <ErrorCode>1</ErrorCode>
    <ErrorText>Общая ошибка</ErrorText>
  </Error>
</ClientCreditShortInfoList>"))
);
```

и не забываем про память [Динамически создаваемые сборки](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer?view=netcore-3.1#dynamically-generated-assemblies). Спасибо Александр

Comment: Хороший по задумке пример. Вот только ресурсы освободить надо: вызвать `Dispose` у `XmlReader` и `StringReader` (обернуть их в `using`). PS: Я слепой, сразу не вник в код, запостил почти то же самое: использование `XmlReader`.

Comment: Думаю, полезно будет указать в ответе, что при использовании `XmlRootAttribute` каждый раз будет создаваться новая сборка сериализатора, что приводит к утечке памяти. [Динамически создаваемые сборки](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer?view=netcore-3.1#dynamically-generated-assemblies). Нужно создать сериализатор один раз и хранить ссылку на него.

Comment: Да конечно, укажу.

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать такой вариант.

Удаляем класс `FindListCreditByClientIDResponse`. Оставляем только класс `Error`.

Десериализацию проводим следующим образом:

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Error));
Error error;

using (var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create("test.xml"))
{
    xmlReader.ReadToFollowing("Error");
    error = (Error)serializer.Deserialize(xmlReader);
}

Console.WriteLine(error.ErrorCode + " " + error.ErrorText);
```

Используем `XmlReader`. С помощью его метода `ReadToFollowing` пропускаем корневой элемент, вернее, все элементы перед "Error".

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте подумать в сторону [XmlDocument](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmldocument). Что-то в стиле:

```
XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
xmlDocument.LoadXml(xmlString);
XmlNodeList xmlNodeList = xmlDocument.SelectNodes("//Error");
foreach (XmlNode xn in xmlNodeList)
{
     //обработка данных каждого тега Error удобным для вас способом
}
```

Где переменная xmlString - ваша xml.

В выборке используется [XPath](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp) `("//Error")`, который, при необходимости, можно доработать под другие варианты.